# オフラインWSUSサーバの構築について

Tags: windows, サーバー管理, vmware

オフラインでWSUSサーバを構築方法についてお聞きしたいです。

以下のサイトに構築方法が書かれています。
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jpwsus/2017/09/06/offline-wsus/

以上の内容を見て構築しようと考えているのですが、

> 「オフライン WSUS サーバーでの実施手順」の「8. WSUSContents フォルダを、オフライン環境のWSUS サーバーへ同じフォルダ構成にてコピーします。この手順でコピーが完了してから、次の手順を実施しないと失敗いたしますので、ご注意ください。

これで、USB等にWSUSContents フォルダにコピーしようと思うのですが「WSUSContents」フォルダを右クリックコピーして、USBに貼り付けを押すと途中で失敗してしまいます。

「エラーを特定できません」というポップアップが表示されてしまいます。
40GBくらいあるファイルを送るのは、難しいのでしょうか。

この現象について、考えられる原因や手順の誤りがあれば、教えていただきたいです。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: リモートデスクトップ接続で操作していて、1つのファイルが40GBあり、コピー&ペーストやドラッグ&ドロップでやろうとしているといった場合は、ファイルのサイズ制限に引っかかっている可能性があるかも。[【Windows 10対応】リモートデスクトップ接続でコピー＆ペーストする方法、できない場合の対処法](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1009/17/news125.html)

Comment: 他には、システムファイルの修復を試す [Windows10でドラッグ＆ドロップができない場合の対処法](http://digisoku.com/windows/windows10-drag-and-drop.html) とか、危険だけどレジストリ操作 [Windows10でファイルをドラッグ&ドロップ出来ない?! を解決する方法](https://pasonal.com/windows10-drag-drop-error/), [ユーザー アカウント制御グループ ポリシーとレジストリ キー設定](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings) してみるとか、その辺は十分注意して自己責任で。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/12521

Comment: `vmware`タグが付いていますが、もう少し詳しい環境の説明があった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。また、貼り付け先のUSBのファイルフォーマットは何になっているか分かりますか？

Comment: @cubickさんコメントを補足。フォーマットによって制限がある(FAT32は1ファイル最大4GB)からです。[USBフラッシュドライブ、またはメモリーカードへ4GB以上のファイルを転送する](https://kb-jp.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5329/)